# Ubuntu 16.04 - (Oracle module for Python) - How to install 'cx_Oracle' module easy way?

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 16.04 (on Docker) and wanted to connect to remote Oracle DB using Python. For that - using cx_oracle module.

Tried:

```
pip install cx_oracle
```

--> Complained about `libaio1` and `libaio-dev` missing..

```
apt-get install libaio1 libaio-dev
```

--> Complained again:
`cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"`

Is there a one command to install `cx_Oracle` properly on Ubuntu 16.04 (or need to do all from source manually -> trying to automate all steps...)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did not find (yet) easy way but this is what I did:

This just worked for me on **Ubuntu 16**:
Download ('instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip' and 'instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip') from Oracle web site and then do following script (you can do piece by piece and I did as a ROOT):

```
apt-get install -y python-dev build-essential libaio1
mkdir -p /opt/ora/
cd /opt/ora/

## Now put 2 ZIP files:
# ('instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip' and 'instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip') 
# into /opt/ora/ and unzip them -> both will be unzipped into 1 directory: /opt/ora/instantclient_12_2 

rm -rf /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh
echo "export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/ora/instantclient_12_2"  >> /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh
echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME"  >> /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh
chmod 777 /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh
source /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh
env | grep -i ora  # This will check current ENVIRONMENT settings for Oracle


rm -rf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf
echo "/opt/ora/instantclient_12_2" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf
ldconfig
cd $ORACLE_HOME  
ls -lrth libclntsh*   # This will show which version of 'libclntsh' you have... --> needed for following line:

ln -s libclntsh.so.12.1 libclntsh.so

pip install cx_Oracle   # Maybe not needed but I did it anyway (only pip install cx_Oracle without above steps did not work for me...)
```

Now python scripts are ready to use 'cx_Oracle'.